# zeppelin standalone for learning purpose with hdfs and spark what do i need to install?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have to say that i'm a little mixed up, I wen't over apache [zeppelin documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/) and I have the following questions.

My end goal is to simply have a local **zeppelin** working with local **hdfs** and local **spark** for simple practice with the minimal installation required.

Questions

1. Is a zeppelin installation enough? does it include the components of local hdfs, spark?
2. If not what else do i need to install in order to have a local spark and hdfs?
3. Do I need to install local hdfs (assuming I want to work with hdfs) and do I need to install local spark (assuming I want to work with local spark).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Zeppelin, see if it comes with a Spark interpreter.

I think it does, and I know [the documentation covers its configuration](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/interpreter/spark.html#configuration). An interpreter is not an installation of Spark, though, just a configuration for starting a process of an external program.

Yes, you'll need to setup and install Hadoop if you want HDFS. However, since you are using a single computer anyway, there's no need for it, and Spark code will work the same against local disk.

I know I've seen Docker containers that have bundled at least Zeppelin and Spark together.

Alternatively, you can use the Hortonworks Sandbox VM, which has everything setup for you already.

Comment: ok cool, this is what i suspected, so zeppelin has only interpreter for spark, but i need to install spark separately.  and in addition as I want `hdfs` for my practicing purposes, this means I will need to install some kind of local hadoop, most probably I would want to do that with docker, sounds fair.

Comment: I only suggest Docker because it doesn't leave remnants of software installation all over the host system.

Comment: cool i just wanted to verify that zeppelin does not come bundled with the real spark (not the interpreter) and without the hdfs.  thanks.

Comment: The documentation seems to suggest it does have a local Spark installed, but I like to run different versions of Spark, so I've always configured it separately